# List of Dictionary to list of tuples for loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a conditional for loop for a list of dictionaries.

The List of Dictionaries is as follows:

```
CLIENTS_EXAMPLE = [
    {
        "first-name": "Elsa",
        "last-name": "Frost",
        "title": "Princess",
        "address": "33 Castle Street, London",
        "loyalty-program": "Gold",
    },
    {
        "first-name": "Anna",
        "last-name": "Frost",
        "title": "Princess",
        "address": "34 Castle Street, London",
        "loyalty-program": "Platinum",
    },
{
        "first-name": "Ben",
        "last-name": "Frost",
        "middle-name": "john",
        "title": "Prince",
        "address": "36a Castle Street, London",
        "loyalty-program": "Platinum",
    },

    {
        "first-name": "Harry",
        "middle-name": "Harold",
        "last-name": "Hare",
        "title": "Mr",
        "email-address": "harry.harold@hare.name",
        "loyalty-program": "Silver",
    },
    {
        "first-name": "Leonnie",
        "last-name": "Lion",
        "title": "Mrs",
        "loyalty-program": "Silver",
    },
]
```

I have to print any individuals with a known Address (not email address) and print out their first, middle (if available) and last name with Address.

The output should look like this:

```
[('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London'),('Prince Ben John Frost', '36a Castle Street, London') ... etc]
```

I have managed to filter out the items and add them to a list of Tuples:

```
def process_clients(segment):

   new_list = []
   new_tuple =()
      for x in segment: #separates the dictionary from the list
         if "address" in x:
             if "middle-name" in x:
                new_tuple += (x["title"] + " " + x["first-name"] + " " + x["middle-name"] + " " + x["last-name"]), (x["address"])
             else:
                new_tuple += (x["title"] + " " + x["first-name"] + " "  + x["last-name"]), (x["address"])
                new_list.append(new_tuple)

       print(new_list)

process_clients(CLIENTS_EXAMPLE)
```

What I get is the following output:

```
[('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London'), ('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London', 'Princess Anna Frost', '34 Castle Street, London'), ('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London', 'Princess Anna Frost', '34 Castle Street, London', 'Prince Ben john Frost', '36a Castle Street, London')]
```

How do I avoid the repetitions in the tuples?

Thanks

Comment: Move `new_tuple` inside the loop. Also, you're only appending when there's no middle name.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a new tuple and then appending to it, you just need to move that `new_tuple` initialization inside the for loop

```
for x in segment:
    new_tuple =()
```

You could also use a list comprehension

```
[("{} {} {}{}".format(
    x["title"],
    x["first-name"],
    x["middle-name"] + " " if "middle-name" in x else "",
    x["last-name"])), x["address"]) for x in segment]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I avoid the repetitions in the tuples?

Don't use `+=`? When you write `new_tuple += ...` that's going to concatenate the existing `new_tuple` and whatever's on the right and set that as the new `new_tuple`. So you're starting with (), then you're adding Alfred so you get `('Alfred',)`, append that to the list, then you add Brenda and get `('Alfred', 'Brenda')` and add *that* to the list, etc...

You can just remove `new_tuple` entirely and append each tuple literal to your output list directly.